# Represent a buffer efficiently as unicode string

Tags: c++, windows, string, unicode, formatting

I have a random buffer.
I need to encode it to a unicode string (utf16 LE.  as used by windows wide-char specification) so it can be used as PWSTR. For example when calling to StringCchPrintfW

A possible solution can be to use base64. But in order to make it a unicode string I will have to add a zero byte after every char, which will be inefficient in space.

And if I will just print the buffer, it might contain '\0' which will terminate the string, or '%' which will effect the formatting (maybe it can be escaped), or other unicode chars that will prevent it from being used in formatting.

The code to generate the string that will be printed, and parsing it in the end will be written in C#, but the buffer will be used in windows C++ to be used in a formatting and then written to a file.

Comment: You have a buffer of *what*? Characters? In what encoding? And why use base64 when you have native functions to [convert narrow multi-byte character buffers to wide-char character buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx) (using UTF-16)? Also see e.g. [this page full of conversion examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx).

Comment: a) So you mean how to represent arbitrary binary datra as string? b) You don´t mean Unicode, but UFT16. c) Yes, it´s space-inefficient for base64, and there are better things (UTF8), but WIndows wants UTF16, period. d) The \0 shouldn´t be a problem if properly coded. Save the length explicitely somewhere.

Comment: Or convert to whatever format and store it compressed using your compression algorithm of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two methods I can think of:

- The easy one: convert each of your bytes in a UTF-16 wchar_t by summing 0x8000 to its value (i.e. you append a 0x80 byte). The efficiency is only 50% but at least you spare the base64 conversion, which would lower the efficiency to 37.5%.
- The efficient but complicated one: read your data in 15-bit chunks (if your total number of bits is not a multiple of 15, pad with null bits at the end). Convert each chunk in a UTF-16 character by adding 0x4000 to its value.  Then add a final wchar_t of value 0xC000 + n, where n (0 <= n <= 14) is the number of padding bits in the final chunk. In exchange for a much more complicated algorithm, you get a very good efficiency: 93.75%.

Both of the method avoid all the perils of using binary data in a UTF-16 format string: no null bytes, no '%' characters, no surrogate pairs, only printable characters (most of which are Chinese ideograms).

Comment: Thanks! I don't filly understand the second method. Which characters exactly do you suggest to use? 0x4000-0xffff? I think some of them are not 'safe' (like 0xFFFF = WEOF). Anyway, this sounds like a really good direction. Could you explain how you choose which chars are 'safe' to use, and which are not?

Comment: And BTW, why avoid surrogate pairs?

Comment: With my second method the character range is 0x4000 - 0xBFFF (plus 0xC000 - 0xC00D for the final wchar). So any dangerous zone is avoided. Surrogates are avoided since they would only add 1-2% efficiency but, by sacrificing the wchar independency (since each high surrogate must be followed by a low one) would add much more contorsions to the encoding algorithm.

Comment: There are some reserved characters in that range - but I don't suppose they would cause any problems.  If you wanted to be absolutely safe, you could create a table of 32,768 known-safe characters and use that, but I think it would be an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I skimmed [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Special_code_points) and found no reserved code points in my zone, but I could surely have missed some lines. I feared something around the 7FFF-8000 boundary, but found no strange control codes there. Surely one could try to use more than 32,768 characters of the set, but squeezing that extra fraction of bit in each wchar would have complicated the algorithm and would have had a very limited impact on the size of the encoded string (since the overhead is just 1/15 of the original data).